# Rails: Accounting logic...Create multiple records at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modeling, accounting

I'm actually trying to develop an accounting Rails application and I'm stuck with the logic...

In fact, I want to simplify the life of the users trying to automate the "dirty" debit / credit stuff.

Let say that I have these fields in my form:

1. Date (xxxx)
2. Bank account (account 1)
3. Expense categorie (account 2)
4. Amount (1000)

In the accounting world, this corresponds to 1 line in the journal like this:

1. Date: xxxx Debit: account2 Credit: account1 Amount:1000

But if I use this logic, calculation and reporting are going to be a nightmare in Rails...

Then my idea is to break it into 2 lignes like:

1. Date: xxxx Account: account2 Amount:1000
2. Date: xxxx Account: account1 Amount:-1000

Does it make sense? If yes, the only way I've found to do it is to create hidden fields in the form updated by a JavaScript code, then save the records (sounds a little bit too nasty to my taste :))

Is there a way to handle it in the controller to generate 2 records in the database without using the "ghost fields" technique?

The problem is becoming more complicated if we imagine to add the VAT logic in it... Same example but with, let's say, 80 of VAT in the operation...

1. Date: xxxx
2. Bank account: account 1
3. Expense category: account 2
4. Amount (with VAT): 1000
5. VAT account: account 3
6. VAT amount: 80

In the accounting world journal it will be:

1. Date: xxxx Debit: account2 Credit: account1 Amount: 1000
2. Date: xxxx Debit: account3 Credit: account1 Amount: 80

In database:

1.Date: xxxx Account: account2 Amount:1000

2.Date: xxxx Account: account1 Amount:-1000

3.Date: xxxx Account: account3 Amount:80

4.Date: xxxx Account: account1 Amount:-80

This means that with the "ghost fields" technique, I need to create 4 hidden lines and so on...

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Dan

Answer (score 3):

You should make the extra records in the model with a callback, not in the controller:

```
class Journal
  # ...

  after_create :update_individual_accounts

  def update_individual_accounts
    debited_account.create_accounting_entry_with self
    credited_account.create_accounting_entry_with self
  end
end
```

Now, whenever you add a new `Journal` record, you'll also create two `AccountingEntry` records on the corresponding accounts.

Comment: Sounds interesting but how I then populate the 2 entries from one form?

Comment: You don't. Your form posts a single `Journal` entry. If the Journal entry is successfully created, `after_create` will be called. Then you will create `AccountingEntry` entries on the `debited_account` and `credited_account`. (Obviously you will have to define the `create_accounting_entry_with` method on your `Account` object.)

Comment: Smart ehhehhe : ) And what would be the same in the case with VAT (4 lines)?

Comment: Just have a `create_with_vat` method on `Journal` which creates the regular entries and the VAT entries.

Comment: Your solution seems to be highly interesting John. I'm a bit novice in Rails so could you provide me with an example of create_with method?

Comment: It's nothing special -- this is just a method you define that would create the regular Journal entry and the VAT Journal entry. Then in your controller, just do `Journal.create_with_vat(params[:journal])`.

Comment: Sorry about sounding so dumb but in fact I don't know to create the create_accounting_entry_with in the model :)

Comment: @Dannoel You may want to ask a separate StackOverflow question about how to create methods in Ruby, then -- that's probably outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

This might fit nicely in a DCI pattern. This means you could create a AddToJournal context in which the Accountant role adds expenses to a journal. This way you have a single place for the logic, which can be easily tested.

DCI is quite a new concept in the Rails world, so there are no conventions on how to implement it, but I really like the aproach taken in this article: http://mikepackdev.com/blog_posts/24-the-right-way-to-code-dci-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

You are doing transfer of amount from account1(debit amount) to account1(credit amount).
It can be done by using standard form with fields to collect `account_frm`, `account_to` & `amount`. Inside code you will load account objects for account_frm & account_to and transfer the money thereafter make the journal entries.

```
= form_tag amount_transfer_url do
  = f.select :account_frm
  = f.select :accoutn_to
  = f.text_field :amount

class AccountsController < ..
 def transfer
  account1, account2 = Account.find_all_by_id(params[:account_frm], params[:accpunt_to])
  account1.transfer(params[:amount], account2)
 end
end

class Account < ..
 def transfer(accnt2, amt)
   # here self is account1
   # make journal entries after successfull transfer
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys and thanks a lot for your help.

I've finally found a way to solve this using inspiration from your various posts.

What I've done is added some code at the model level to handle an after_create action like:

after_create :journalize

then I've defined :journalize action in another def like:

def journalize
   Ligne.create({with the various data to create})
   end

SO thanks again for your help.
Peace
Dan

Answer (score 0):

I came across this gem for accounting ledgers: https://github.com/mbulat/plutus

From the readme:

> The plutus plugin provides a complete double entry accounting system for use in any Ruby on Rails application. The plugin follows general Double Entry Bookkeeping practices. All calculations are done using BigDecimal in order to prevent floating point rounding errors. The plugin requires a decimal type on your database as well.
>
> The system consists of tables that maintains your accounts, transactions and debits and credits. Each transaction can have many debits and credits. The transaction table, which records your business transactions is, essentially, your accounting Journal.
>
> Posting to a Ledger can be considered to happen automatically, since Accounts have the reverse has_many relationship to either its credit or debit transactions.